# Deploying different branches using Deployer

Tags: php, laravel, php-deployer

I am learning to use Deployer to deploy my Laravel application to staging / production environments.

The below config works, but it always deploys the same code. Is it possible to set staging to only deploy the `develop` branch, and set production to deploy the `master` branch?

```php
namespace Deployer;

require 'recipe/laravel.php';

set('application', 'my_app');
set('repository', 'git@github.com:account/repo-name.git');
set('php_fpm_version', '8.0');
set('git_tty', false);

add('shared_files', []);
add('shared_dirs', []);
add('writable_dirs', []);

host('staging')
    ->hostname('hostname-here')
    ->user('username')
    ->identityFile('~/.ssh/id_rsa')
    ->multiplexing(false)
    ->set('deploy_path', '~/staging');

host('production')
    ->hostname('hostname-here')
    ->user('username')
    ->identityFile('~/.ssh/id_rsa')
    ->multiplexing(false)
    ->set('deploy_path', '~/production');

task('build', function () {
    run('cd {{release_path}} && build');
});

after('deploy:failed', 'deploy:unlock');
before('deploy:symlink', 'artisan:migrate');
```

Comment: It looks like this issue might relate to you're situation https://github.com/deployphp/deployer/issues/2676  It looks like there used to be a way to get the branch option set on the host that is no longer working in 7.0

Answer (score 3):

You can set the branch with `->set('branch', 'master')` in your host configuration.

```yaml
host('staging')
  ->set('branch', 'develop')

host('production')
  ->set('branch', 'master')
```